# Sending MMS Using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, cordova-3, mms

i have a cross platform app. currently developing the android version. Right now am using SMS app to send sms from my application. 
Here is the SMS application,

https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin

but i want to send images as MMS via phonegap. is that possible. Am populating my data on a div. Is there someway i can copy that image on that div to native  SMS composer to send as MMS?

Comment: you will need another plugin for sending MMS, but as far as I know it doesn't exists yet

Comment: i couldn't find any either. atlast i made some modification in sms plugin and somehow make it work to an extend. Any good answers or help will be still sppreciated.. thanks!

Comment: but did you get it? if you created a fork of the plugin, share the link

Comment: Am not an advanced coder. i forked the sms plugin and started a new branch. btw iam crating a repo for the first time. i dont even know if i did it in the right way. Anyway take a  look at it here. https://github.com/christyrajupaul/Phonegap-MMS-Plugin

Comment: hey @KRIZTE, I am new the maintainer of https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin (former https://github.com/aharris88/phonegap-sms-plugin). You should open an issue on the new repository, I would love to add support for MMS to this plugin.